# Why is $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^{-1}}$ defined when $x=0?$

Tags: real-analysis

> Why is $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^{-1}}$ defined when $x=0?$

There's something that confuses me:
If we take the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^{-1}}$ then we can say it is equal to $f(x)=x\sin x$ and therefore $f(0)=0$. But if we try to get $f(0)$ from the original function we get $f(0)=\dfrac{\sin 0}{\frac{1}{0}}$ which I'd expect to be undefined just like $\frac{\sin 0}{0}$ is undefined. So how come it is defined and equal to $0?$

Comment: Do you know what is limit?

Comment: When you take $f(0)=\tfrac{\sin 0}{(1/0)}$, observe that in the numerator you have a number and the denominator is infinite. Some number divided by infinity is zero, there is no indetermination here.

Comment: yes I know what is a limit, and yet this question has nothing to do with limits. I am asking why the expression is defined, not why it is continuous or anything like that. 
@user326159 your answer seems awfully wrong to me, I hope someone else can elaborate.

Comment: $f(0)$ is not defined, since there is a division by zero in a subexpression in $f(0)$. However, it's possible to rewrite $f(x)$ in a form that does not have $1/x$, so $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That is what I would expect, but all online calculators show it is defined on x=0, and my lecturer also mentioned it is defined there...

Comment: Sometimes the majority is wrong. This kind of simplification, while obvious, does only yield an exactly equivalent function where the domain does not change, and here it does at $0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, can I ask you another question concerning this specific question but regarding its integral on [0,1]? I'm not sure if private messages are available here. If not it is also ok but it would be nice since you see the point that bothers me here.

Comment: Considering there is a removable ingularity at $0$, you can just integrate $x\sin x$, and a primitive is easy to find by identification of coefficients, where you write $\int x\sin x dx=(ax+b)\cos x+(cx+d)\sin x+C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no hesitation, 
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{-1}}$$ is *not* defined at $x=0$ because the denominator is not defined.

---

You may not claim that

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{-1}}=x\sin(x)$$ at $x=0$, though
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{-1}}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin(x)$$ is true.

---

For the same reason,

$$x\sin(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x=0,\\\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^{-1}},&x\ne0\end{cases}$$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one could "simply" say that it is:

$$x=\frac{1}{x^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} $$

One could claim that the function $f(x) = x$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$ but in order to define at $x=0$ it is a must that one should be more rigorous. Keep in mind, though, that expressing things as fractions results in restrictions for the given variables. Thus, in order to revert to an expression such as the equalities at the RHS of the first line, one should apply specific restrictions.

It is just a matter of convention to be honest. I prefer to be rigorous and 100% correct. Thus I would not say that $\dfrac{1}{x^{-1}}$ is defined at $x=0$.

If you want to express the function $f(x) = x$ as the fraction above, then you may exclude the case of $x=0$ and note that its value is:
$$f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x^{-1}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^{-1}}.$$
The limits are easy to calculate.

Then the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, \ x =0 \\ \dfrac{1}{x^{-1}} &,x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$
is defined rigorously.

**Edit:** As I saw your comment about online calculators, it is **important** to mention that computative systems tend to simplify expressions sometimes, not taking into account such sensitive matters. Thus, we should always revert to rigorous terms to be sure and precise.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I was trying to explain exactly that in the length but I updated accordingly to be more precise :)

Comment: Your last example is flawed. There is a typo $\ne\color{red}1$, and setting $f(0)=1$ does not make the function continuous.